# Assert in TestNG (Actual int value, Expected int value)

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium2, testng, assert

Is there anyway to assert that,

actual int value = expected int value **not equal to 0**

Something like,

```
Assert.assertEquals(length, 0);
```

Comment: can you please give some example?

Comment: Are you referring to this: `Assert.assertTrue(actIntValue==expIntValue && expIntValue > 0);`

Comment: Are you trying to check two things? That actual value = expected value and that actual value <> 0?

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void assertEquals(int actual,
                                int expected,
                                java.lang.String message)
```

Asserts that two ints are equal. If they are not, an AssertionFailedError, with the given message, is thrown.
Parameters:
actual - the actual value
expected - the expected value
message - the assertion error message

Comment: You may visit this Link for more details for  Assert in TestNG  :

http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/Assert.html

Answer (score 2):

The [TestNG Assert documentation](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/Assert.html) describes a function `assertNotEquals`

```
Assert.assertNotEquals(length, 0);
```

This does what you want I guess, if not you can also check with assertEquals with some extra code.

Pseudo code:

```
result = false
if (length == 0 ) {
  result = true
}
Assert.assertEquals(result, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `assertThat` instead of simple `assertEquals` or `assertNotEquals` for the reasons described on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701113/why-should-i-use-hamcrest-matcher-and-assertthat-instead-of-traditional-assert):

```
assertThat(actual, is(not(equalTo(expected)));
assertThat(actual, is(not(equalTo(0)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `assertTrue` in **TestNG**.

```
Assert.assertTrue(length > 0);
```